# Docker ps -a doesn't show a stopped mysql client running container

Tags: mysql, docker

I am connecting to a mysql container using another container running mysql client. When I exit out of this client the container stops obviously. But when I do a `docker ps -a` this container doesn't show. I have not been able to find a reason for this. I am following [these](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) instructions to start the containers. Any ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--rm` option passed along `docker run` automatically removes the container after its stopped.

See [clean up flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/clean-up-rm):

> By default a container’s file system persists even after the container exits. This makes debugging a lot easier (since you can inspect the final state) and you retain all your data by default. But if you are running short-term foreground processes, these container file systems can really pile up. If instead you’d like Docker to automatically clean up the container and remove the file system when the container exits, you can add the --rm flag

Comment: I should've known this.